# get_boudingbox not defined error (opencv2,python)

Tags: python, opencv, face-detection

I am trying to extract faces from images by creating bounding boxes, but I am getting an error shown below.

First code block:

```py
def get_predicition(image):
    """Expects the image input, this image further cropped to face
    and the cropped face image will be sent for evalution funtion 
    finally 
    returns the annotated reusult with bounding box around the face. 
    """
    height, width = image.shape[:2]
    try: # If in case face is not detected at any frame
        face = face_detector(image, 1)[0]  # Face detection
        x, y, size = get_boundingbox(face=face, width=width, height=height) # Calling to get bound box around the face
    except IndexError:
        pass
    cropped_face = image[y:y+size, x:x+size] # cropping the face 
    output,label = evaluate(cropped_face) # Sending the cropped face to get classifier result 
    font_face = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX # font settings
    thickness = 2
    font_scale = 1
    if label=='Real':
        color = (0,255, 0)
    else:
        color = (0, 0, 255)
    x = face.left()    # Setting the bounding box on uncropped image
    y = face.top()
    w = face.right() - x
    h = face.bottom() - y
    cv2.putText(image, label+'_'+str('%.2f'%output)+'%', (x, y+h+30), 
            font_face, font_scale,
            color, thickness, 2) # Putting the label and confidence values

    return cv2.rectangle(image, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), color, 2)# draw box over face
```

Second code block:

```py
cropped_face =[]
for image in images:
    faces = face_detector(image[0], 1)
    height, width = image[0].shape[:2]
    try: # If in case face is not detected at any frame   
        x, y, size = get_boundingbox(face=faces[0], width=width, height=height)
    except IndexError:
        continue
cropped_face.append([image[0][y:y+size, x:x+size],image[1]])
```

The first code block runs without any errors but when I try to run the second code block. I am getting the error shown below:

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-48-52e274eb31f6> in <module>
      5     try: # If in case face is not detected at any frame
      6 
----> 7         x, y, size = get_boundingbox(face=faces[0], width=width, height=height)
      8     except IndexError:
      9         continue

NameError: name 'get_boundingbox' is not defined
```